# Start services with contain in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need a Powershell Script which start all my services 'example*' without the services reeded in from a .txt file

(sry, my English sucks I know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$restrictedServices = @(Get-Content X:\restricted.txt) -join '|'
Get-Service example* | ?{$_.Name -notmatch $restrictedServices} | Start-Service -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
Get-Service -Name * -ComputerName PCNameHere | Where {$_.Name -like "example*"} | Restart-Service -Force -Verbose
```